# Changing column width in Joomla layout

Tags: html, css, templates, iframe, joomla

I'm currently including an iframe from another website, but can't change the design so that I can fully fit in the iframe.

http://pacbetting.com/dropping-odds

The code for the iframe is

```
<p><iframe src="http://www.oddshelp.com/f_dropping.php" width="693" height="809" frameborder="0"></iframe></p>
```

No matter what width and height I choose the scroller still overlaps and the right part of the frame can't be seen. I assume this is due to the middle column of my website not being wide enough. I use protostar but don't know how to modify the template as one section only won't change.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to add scrolling to the horizontal axis.  Try this:

```
<iframe src="http://www.oddshelp.com/f_dropping.php" height="809" frameborder="0" overflow="scroll" scrolling="auto" ></iframe>
```

Comment: Didn't manage to work, this is what it looks like now: http://pacbetting.com/dropping-odds